# Question in line of proof for first isomorphism theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

> Let $\phi: G_1 \to G_2$ be a group homomorphism.
>
> Let $\ker \left({\phi}\right)$ be the kernel of $\phi$.
>
> Then:
>   $\operatorname {Im} \left({\phi}\right) \cong G_1 / \ker \left({\phi}\right)$
>   where $\cong$ denotes group isomorphism.
>
> Proof:
>
> Let $K = \ker \left({\phi}\right)$.
>
> $G_1 / K$ exists.
>
> We need to establish that the mapping $\theta: G_1 / K \to G_2$ defined as:
>   :$\forall x \in G_1: \theta \left({x K}\right) = \phi \left({x}\right)$
>   is well-defined.
>
> That is, we need to ensure that:
>   $\forall x, y \in G: x K = y K \implies \theta \left({x K}\right) = \theta \left({y K}\right)$
>
> Let $x, y \in G: x K = y K$. Then:
>
> $xK = yK$
>
> $\iff x^{-1} y \in K = \ker \left({\phi}\right)$
>
> $\iff \phi \left({x^{-1} y}\right) = e_{G_2}$
>
> $\iff \left({\phi \left({x}\right)}\right)^{-1} \phi \left({y}\right) = e_{G_2}$
>
> $\iff \phi \left({x}\right) = \phi \left({y}\right)$
>
> Thus we see that $\theta$ is well-defined.

I don't understand the two lines here:

> $\iff \phi \left({x^{-1} y}\right) = e_{G_2}$
>
> $\iff \left({\phi \left({x}\right)}\right)^{-1} \phi \left({y}\right) = e_{G_2}$

I know that $\phi \left({x^{-1} y}\right) = {\phi \left({x^{-1}}\right)} \phi \left({y}\right)$, but I don't understand how to get from $\phi \left({x^{-1}}\right)\phi \left({y}\right) = \left({\phi \left({x}\right)}\right)^{-1}\phi \left({y}\right)$.

Comment: Because $\phi$ is homomorphism, then $\phi(x^{-1})\phi(x) = \phi(e) = e$. So you get $phi(x^{-1}) = \phi(x)^{-1}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\phi(x)\phi(x)^{-1}=e_2=\phi(e_1)=\phi(xx^{-1})=\phi(x)\phi(x^{-1})$